# javascript adding code to a parent iframe

Tags: javascript

been struggling with this for some time now, im trying to add a function to the main window from an iframe, but the only way i can get it to work is by providing an eval function in the main window and passing it a string, such as:

```
--main window--
    function evalcmd(c){
      eval(c);
    }
--iframe--
    parent.evalcmd('alert(location.href)');
```

ideally i would like something of the form

```
--iframe--
    parent.myalert=new Function('alert(location.href);');
```

however this seems to be called from the context of the iframe, ie the alert references the iframes filename

sorry new edit

the alert is trying to show the context that the new Function operates in, if i had

```
--main window--
<div id="txt1" style="left:50px;">somettxt</div>

--iframe--
parent.movetxt=new Function("document.getElemenById('txt1').style.left='35px';");
```

this would throw an error, element 'txt1' not found in iframe
however,

```
--main window--
function evalcmd(c){
  eval(c);
}
--iframe--
parent.evalcmd("document.getElemenById.('txt1').style.left='35px';");
```

would be fine, 
is there a way to have this functionality without the use of eval?
i basically have a lot of code i want to add to the parent window, so dont want to have to go through adding parent. to varname/functionname on all references

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
parent.alert("your message");
parent.alert(parent.location.href + "\n" + window.location.href);
```